# Where do I find a version of brew for high sierra?

Tags: high-sierra, homebrew

My laptop is using High Sierra os and I just installed homebrew. However, after running brew doctor I see the following:

```
Warning: You are using macOS 10.13.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
You will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Twitter or any other official channels. You are responsible for resolving
any issues you experience while you are running this
old version.
```

Where do I downgrade my brew for high sierra support?

Note: This laptop does not support any version higher than high sierra.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the message. Seems to me that you already have `brew` installed, and it's just telling you that they no longer guarantee it to work on High Sierra.

Comment: @Tuesday The version I installed is for Mojave onwards. So I need to downgrade the brew version.

Comment: Use macports rather than homebrew  they have versions that work on each version of osx going back to Tiger

Comment: This message actually says that the packages installed might be broken due to old OSX, rather than brew itself. You might want to switch to macports, due to better support for old hardware/software.

Comment: @BerkIlgar that is why I asked if I can find an older version of brew and stated that I am using High Sierra.

Comment: @SidneySousa and that is why I mentioned it. It is not related with the brew only, it is about the formulae as well as the packages, even if you can downgrade brew you might still end-up with broken packages. Switching to macports is the wise route.

Comment: @BerkIlgar I just installed macports now and installed php8, but when I type php -v I still see the older version(7.1). Is there anything else that needs to be done after running port install command?

Comment: @SidneySousa MacPorts does detect the os. I believe you should be fine.

Comment: @SidneySousa That is a separate question but youy need to check that you have /opt/local/bin on your PATH https://guide.macports.org/#installing.shell